# How can "Alternate Configuration" for Ipv4 be re-enabled with Windows 10?

Tags: networking, windows-10, ipv4

In earlier versions of Windows a network interface could be configured with "Obtain an IP Address Automatically" (e.g use DHCP) as the primary configuration, and an additional IP address could be User Configured on the "Alternate Configuration" tab. Selecting the User Configured address option unchecked the "Automatic Private IP Address" (APIA) option.

This is useful for assigning a specific address when there is no DHCP server available.  APIA has limited usefulness.

In Windows 10, it doesn't work.  Regardless of whether a user configured alternate address is entered, the interface is assigned an APIA  (169.254.0.0)

The setting for Alternate Configuration user configured address still exists, but seems to be ignored.

Is there any way to restore the older behavior where the user configured address is used when a DHCP server is not available?